# Outlook 2013: Hotkey to show just unread messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotkeys

When I'm looking at my inbox in Outlook 2013, there are two convenient buttons called "All" and "Unread". When I press "Unread", it shows just the unread items, and I can toggle back to "All" to see all my messages.

**My question:** Is there a hotkey for pressing these buttons? I prefer to avoid using the mouse wherever possible.